# Preventing Abuse: Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, cloudflare

What is the best way to stop an attacker from triggering a Cloud Function repeatedly, causing a huge bill or causing the project to run into quota limits?

Some ideas:

- Use [RTDB](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) or [Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events) triggers as much as possible, since writes to those are protected by those products' [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/)
- Put functions behind a service like [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/ddos/)
- Set up [billing alerts](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6293540?hl=en), so a notification is sent if the monthly bill is unusually large

Comment: This is a broad discussion-type question without a correct answer for all types of functions.  This was in fact discussed today at length in the Firebase Slack, which is a more appropriate place for this sort of question.  http://firebase.community/

Comment: Did you manage to put Firebase functions behind Cloudflare? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47092796/353276).

Short breakdown of items from my answer :

1. Limit the type of requests
2. Authenticate if you can
3. Check for origin
4. Use a load balancer in between
5. Use something like [Cloudflare Page Rules](https://www.cloudflare.com/features-page-rules/)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Is it possible to limit the number requests made from a particular IP?
My concern is, even if we have authenticate users, anyone can fire on GET requests infinitely and won't it be a problem on billing side?

Comment: @Ayyappa Not directly using Firebase / Cloud Functions to the best of my knowledge. You can however do two things if this is really important for you. 1) Set up a database to log requesting IPs and check the database for every request. 2) Use something like Cloudflare page rules to apply DNS level limitations / control API access etc. Neither of these are ideal, but I guess that in part a tradeoff of serverless infrastructure. (Until someone makes a native / well-integrated solution that is of course)

Comment: Thank you. Cloudflare is the one I need to explore :)